# Android NDK with OpenGLES2 Undefined reference to glcalls

Tags: c++, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

Following the tutorial on : http://www.learnopengles.com/calling-opengl-from-android-using-the-ndk/.
Created all the necessary files, but when trying to build I get the errors :

> D:\svn-Genicap3D\trunk\frontend_android\Genicap3D\app\src\main\jni\core\game.cpp
>   Error:(6) undefined reference to 'glClearColor'
>   Error:(14) undefined reference to `glClear'

**game.cpp**

```
#include "game.h"
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>

void on_surface_created() {
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

void on_surface_changed() {
    // No-op
}

void on_draw_frame() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}
```

**android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH:=$(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Here we give our module name and source file(s)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libgame
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Wall -Wextra
LOCAL_LDLIBS :=  -llog -lnativehelper -lGLESv2
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES += exceptions
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog libnativehelper libGLESv2
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := coreBridge.cpp core/game.cpp

# To build the whole .so
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../core/src/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%) LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../core/include


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

game.cpp and .h are in core map which is in the same map as the .mk files

I have tried to include alot from other answers but none seem to work.
Feel free to ask for more files.

Comment: How did you build your project? Have you tried to build hello-gl2 NDK sample?

Comment: I am currently trying to, using Android studio as IDE. I can't seem to run that sample just as project neither as an imported module in an empty project.

Answer (score 3):

as you're using Android Studio, your Makefiles are ignored by default and new ones are generated on-the-fly, so OpenGL ES2 lib isn't properly referenced.

This feature is how NDK builds are currently supported from Android Studio, but it's deprecated while a better way to do it is in the work.

You can still choose to use it and specify inside your build.gradle that you need to link to OpenGL ES:

```
android {
 ...
 defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            moduleName "game"
            ldLibs "GLESv2"               
        }
    }
}
```

But the best for now, in my view, is to deactivate the built-in NDK support and get your Makefiles to be used instead:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        ...

        sourceSets.main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set .so files directory to libs
            jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
        }

        // call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
        task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
            if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
            } else {
                commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
            }
        }

        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems to solve, but the ndk needs to be in src/main now i suppose? Instead of on one fixed location

Comment: Your ndk sources should be in src/main/jni as defined in the build.gradle file, but you can choose another location if you want and modify the config accrodingly.

Comment: I can't seem to get it working, with your last option I get the 'ndk-build.cmd' not recognized, followed by command ndk-build.cmd finished with non-zero exit value 1. And if I use your first option I get "GLESv2" not found

Comment: If ndk-build.cmd isn't found, you should add the path to your ndk to your environment path. This is weird for GLESv2.. can you give the exact error message ?

Comment: I've copied the whole ndk folder (from download) into src/main/jni, the ndk-build.cmd file is in it, but still isn't recognized (location is: src/main/jni/ndk-build.cmd). After putting the whole folder there the error from 'GLESv2' changed :     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'. Error Code:
 255
Output:
 "C:\Users\bram\AppData\Local\Android\ndk\prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/make.exe": Interrupt/Exception caught (code = 0xc00000fd, addr = 0000000000420386)

Comment: you shouldn't copy the ndk itself into your project. Keep it anywhere else, inside its own directory without blank spaces in the path (Downloads is fine), and add it to your path. The second issue you've seen may be related to your path: http://hdrlab.org.nz/articles/windows-development/make-interrupt-exception-caught-code-0xc00000fd-addr-0x4217b/

Comment: I've got that all fixed and it seems to progress, although I'm now stuck on : 'target '=' given more than once in the same rule' in the build-binary.mk.

Comment: I think this is the issue: inside your Android.mk file, `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` and `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` should be on different lines.

Comment: I've got this in my Android.mk now : 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += coreBridge.cpp core/game.cpp $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../core/include on seperate lines. tried with := and += in all four ways, neither luck.  Thanks already for all the help provided !

Comment: Shouldn't it be `FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/core/src/*.cpp)` instead of `FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../core/src/*.cpp)` ? keep the `+=` for `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio you can go into the CMakeLists.txt file and add

```
target_link_libraries(EGL
                      GLESv2)
```